# Передача данных в ссылке urlpatterns listview django get_context_data

Tags: python, django

Как передать данные в ссылке в listview?

**ursl.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
        path('test/<str:data>/', TestView.as_view(), name='test'),
    ]
```

**view.py**

```
class TestView(ListView):
    model = Test
    template_name = 'test/test.html'
    context_object_name = 'test'
```

как получить **данные data** в классе TestView?

понимаю, что через self.kwargs, но не могу понять как

Answer (score 0):

нашел ответ, делюсь

**ursl.py**

проверяем ссылку, если она содержит после test/ строку, то запускаем класс TestView в views.py

```
urlpatterns = [
        path('test/<str:data>/', TestView.as_view(), name='test'),
    ]
```

**views.py**

вызываем get_context_data и добавляем в словарь context переменную data, которая хранится в словаре kwargs

```
 class TestView(ListView):
        model = Test
        template_name = 'test/test.html'
        context_object_name = 'test'

        def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
            context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['data']= self.kwargs['data']
            return context
```

**test.html**

```
{{ data }} - вывод в шаблоне
{% test_tags data %} - если надо передать переменную в tags
```

**test_tags.py**

```
register = template.Library()
@register.inclusion_tag('test/test_tags.html')
def install_plugin(arg1='empty'):
    return {'data' : arg1}
```